# In Java are composite types comparable to generic classes?

Tags: java, class, types, composite, primitive

Im newbie to `Java` language .
I studied the differences between `Primitive Data Types` and `Classes`.
My book took particular attention on the `Composite Data Types` and that made me doubt that they differ from both `Primitive types` and `Classes`. 
Is that true? Thanks!

Comment: Composites have references to other classes as private data members.  That is different from both primitives and simple classes.  Why do you doubt it?   It makes no more sense to compare different classes in programming that it does to compare chalk to cheese in real life.

Comment: Primitive types aren't implemented as classes , the compositive types ?

Comment: Primitives and their wrappers are different.  Integer is not what I would call a composite class.  Your question makes no sense to me.

Comment: No, composite types and generic classes haven’t got anything to do with each other. A composite type may sometimes be generic, of course, but it’s a different thing from being composite.

Answer (score 1):

Composite data types is a very general term. It refers to a data type, created and customized by user,  by combining primitive data types and other Composite data types.

- `C` language have structures as composite data types.
- Object-oriented languages like `Java` have class as composite data types.

> Whether primitive data types can be
>   compared to composite(user-defined) data types,

**It varies from language to language.**

- C++ allows you, by defining overloaded function in your class, which accepts primitive data type.
- Type-insensitive language like python allows allows you to do so, by requiring you to define **eq** method in your class.
- However Java doesn't allow that. However wrapper classes for primitive data types like integer, float, etc. are exception to this rule.